# How initialize my blackberry device?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, mobile-application

I will develop a mobile applicaton destinated to Blackberry 10 and I have the "***Balckberry Dev Alpha B***" device to test with.

**Problem** : When I turn on the device for the first time, it ask me to intialize the device parameters (language, location, available wifi connection etc.). All went well until the licence agreement, it  still stuck in this step : it can not load the licence (I try to update the OS using ["blackberry OS autoload"](https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberry10devalpha/devalpha_update.html) but unfortuately the same problem), I tried to configure the device using "***balckberry software manager***" but it ask me to configure the device first before connect it to the manager.

I can not find a solution for this, what should I do ? Thanks for any ideas .. !

Comment: You mean the "Developer program has ended" message?

Comment: In addition to the previous point, be aware that the device must, repeat must, have WiFi connectivity at that point to download the agreement in the language you have specified.  Of course if there is no longer a license agreement because the device is no longer supported, this might help.